# Compare a value in whereHas with parent data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to use `where` in a `whereHas` and compare this condition with the value of the parent element.

Concretely, I have an `events` table and I would like to compare the end date of my events with the end date of the `health_items` element.

```
Event::where('team_id', Auth::user()->currentTeam->id)
           ->whereHas('animals', function ($query) use ($decodedId) {
              $query->where('animals.id', $animal_id)
           ->whereHas('health_items', function ($query) {
       $query->where('date_end', 'events.end');
    });
 })
```

In my solution, which doesn't work, I try to access my ʻevents `table using ʻevents.end`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is you are asserting that `date_end` is equal to the string `events.end`. Use `whereColumn()` instead.

```
Event::where('team_id', Auth::user()->currentTeam->id)
    ->whereHas('animals', function ($query) use ($decodedId) {
        $query->where('animals.id', $animal_id)
            ->whereHas('health_items', function ($query) {
                $query->whereColumn('date_end', 'events.end');
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it with whereRaw

```
$query->whereRaw("date_end = events.end");
```